# dataframe not droping duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have two dataframes :

df:

```
id    Name    Number    Stat
1     co       4         
2     ma       98       
3     sa       0
```

df1:

```
id   Name    Number     Stat
1     co     4     
2     ma     98         5%
```

I want to merge both dataframes in 1 (dfnew) and i want it as follow:

```
    id    Name    Number    Stat
     1     co       4         
     2     ma       98       5%
     3     sa       0
```

I used

```
dfnew = pd.concat([df, df2])
dfnew = df_row.drop_duplicates(keep='last')
```

I am not getting the result i want. the dataframes are joined but duplicates are not deleted. I need help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try pd.merge function with inner/ outer based on requirement.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need check only first 3 columns for duplicates:

```
dfnew = pd.concat([df, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['id','Name','Number'], keep='last')
print (dfnew)
   id Name  Number Stat
2   3   sa       0  NaN
0   1   co       4  NaN
1   2   ma      98   5%
```